# How does rust simply get a return from a closure

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures, lifecycle, tauri

Here's the problem I'm having with tauri.

'return' shows you the return value I need, and I know for a fact that writing it this way does not work at all.

'pick_file' is called asynchronously, and I know that message passing seems to work, but is there an easier way to get the value I need.

```rust
#[tauri::command]
fn open_file() -> String {
    dialog::FileDialogBuilder::default()
        .add_filter("data", &["json"])
        .pick_file(|path_buf| match path_buf {
            Some(p) => return format!("{}", p.to_str().unwrap()),
            _ => return "".into()
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `return` in a closure returns from the closure and not from the function that contains it.

The more fundamental issue is that you can't return a `String` from `open_file()` if you use `FileDialogBuilder::pick_file()`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/api/dialog/struct.FileDialogBuilder.html#method.pick_file), `pick_file()` is non-blocking and returns immediately without waiting for the user to pick the file. What you can do in the closure is send the file down a channel, and pick it up elsewhere.